# Does semicolon split multiple commands in double quoted string?

Tags: bash

The command

```
cd /tmp; echo Hello
```

generates

```
Hello
```

Quoted, the command

```
"cd /tmp; echo Hello"
```

generates

```
-bash: cd /tmp; echo Hello: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why this is so? I am trying to use the quotes so I can build up a command chain and pass it through ssh on to a remote host. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes don't define strings; they define *words*, so in this case your command consists of exactly one word (containing lots of whitespace in addition to a `;`). The first (non-assignment) word on a command line is treated as the name of the command, resulting in the error you see.

`ssh` works differently because the entire string is passed to a *second* shell on the remote end to be evaluated again. Just like you can run `sh -c "cd /tmp; echo hello"` on your local host, the following two commands are roughly equivalent:

```
ssh host "cd /tmp; echo hello"
ssh host sh -c "cd /tmp; echo hello"
```

Answer (score -1):

Semicolon sign interpreted literally inside double quotes. 
More explanation can't be found here https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html